# remix dev doesn't detect file changes inside a Docker container with volumes configured

Tags: docker, docker-compose, remix.run

When I run my Remix application inside a Docker container with еру `remix dev` command, it doesn't detect file changes inside the app directory **when there are volumes configured**. It doesn't matter if I change files through volumes or through an attached VS Code instance. As soon as I remove volumes from docker-compose.yml it works fine. Additionally, it does detect changes in files located directly inside the volume directory. For example, if the volume mapping is `./web:/code`, it won't detect any file changes, but if it's `./web/app:/code/app` it will detect changes in root.tsx, entry.client.tsx, entry.server.tsx and every other file located inside the app directory, but not inside any sub directories.

I have tried using nodemon and it has the same behavior when run without the `--watch-legacy` flag, but works when the flag is present.

web directory:

```
│   .dockerignore
│   Dockerfile
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   remix.config.js
│   remix.env.d.ts
│   tailwind.config.ts
│   tsconfig.json
│
├───app
│   │   entry.client.tsx
│   │   entry.server.tsx
│   │   root.tsx
│   │   tailwind.css
│   │
│   ├───routes
│   │       index.tsx
│   │
│   └───utils
│           db.server.ts
│
└───prisma
    └───schema.prisma
```

remix.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
module.exports = {
  ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*"],
  appDirectory: "app",
  assetsBuildDirectory: "public/build",
  serverBuildPath: "build/index.js",
  publicPath: "/build/",
  tailwind: true,
  serverModuleFormat: "cjs",
  future: {
    v2_errorBoundary: true,
    v2_meta: true,
    v2_normalizeFormMethod: true,
    v2_routeConvention: true,
  },
};
```

.dockerignore:

```
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
todo.md

node_modules/
build/
public/build/
prisma/migrations/
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20.1.0

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npx prisma generate && npx remix dev
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
      - 8002:8002
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
      WEB_SESSION_SECRET: ${WEB_SESSION_SECRET}
    volumes:
      - ./web:/code
      - /code/node_modules/
      - /code/build/
      - /code/public/build/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. I fixed it by adding

```
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

to the environement variables in the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I added these env variables in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```